Would the Persian equivalent of Anglo/Franco/Russo… be Persico? (from the Latin Persicus) Can I write “Persico-Egyptian”
In my paper I am talking about something which refers to both Egypt and Persia, so to make it short I first thought it should be “Perso-Egyptian” but sometimes it's not as simply as that, like “Luso” for Portuguese.

Parsi-Egyptian has billions of hits.

Wiktionary has a list which includes Irano- and Perso-.

@YosefBaskin Not when I search for it. Can you post some of your results?

I only found two results for “Parsi-Egyptian”
https://www.rimfirecentral.com/threads/cz-452-magazines-polymer-vs-metal.220979/
https://www.academia.edu/58984995/Variations_in_ribosomal_DNA_and_mitochondrial_DNA_among_chromosomal_species_of_subterranean_mole_rats?uc-sb-sw=87589433

I just realized that the persian alphabet is called the Perso-Arabic script. So perhaps Perso-Egyptian would be acceptable

https://www.jstor.org/stable/986072 this article uses Perso

https://books.google.ca/books?id=yboaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=%22persico-egyptian%22&source=bl&ots=4k1KETx3fe&sig=ACfU3U1NklCZWmBmw0jfQrsQtSZyFPoD0A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRncK536aFAxUcF1kFHbhYBNAQ6AF6BAgTEAI#v=onepage&q=%22persico-egyptian%22&f=false this uses persico

OED: persico (n.) Now rare. A cordial prepared by macerating the kernels of peaches, apricots, almonds, etc., in spirits. -- 1709 Tincture of Saffron, Barbadoes-Water, Persico. D. Manley, Secret Memoirs 108.

@Greybeard Interestingly, persico (the drink) is called as such because it comes from the latin persicum (peach) which is the shortened form of persicum pomum (persian fruit). So, truly, a persico is a persian.

FYI, googling "Parsi-Egyptian" in quotes shows this page as the top link.

Why, please? Why would 'Persian-Egyptian' not work?

A quick search of Google Books turns up exactly one unique match for "Persico-Egyptian"—from Josiah Conder, The Modern Traveler: A Popular Description, Geographical, Historical, and Topographical, of the Various Countries of the Globe: Africa, volume 1 (1829):

We have the authority, indeed, of both Strabo and Pliny, for considering them [Barca and Ptolemais] as the same city; and as Ptolemais must have had some name before it received that of the Egyptian sovereign, it seems not improbable that it succeeded to that of Barca, on the ruin of the original city of that name, by the Persico-Egyptian army in alliance with the Cyrenean Queen, when its inhabitants are said to have retired to the port.

In contrast a corresponding search for "Perso-Egyptian" turns up about fifty unique matches, ranging in time from 1843 to 2023. Here are two such matches at or near each end of that time interval. From Samuel Birch, "Observations on the Xanthian Marbles Recently Deposited in the British Museum" (1843):

These monuments are probably not older than the Persian invasion, 546 B. C.; although, perhaps, some of the earliest executed after it, exhibiting a mixed kind of treatment, allied on the one hand to the early Greek or Phœnico-Greek, and on the other to the Perso-Egyptian, such as occurs on the staircase at Persepolis, for the Persians and Medes derived their arts from their vassals of Greek blood in Asia Minor, and from Egypt, and had no original developement of native art.

From David Masson, The British Museum, Historical and Descriptive (1850):

Egyptian antiquities consist, therefore, of four distinct classes, according to the epochs to which they belong:—antiquities of the period of the Pharaohs, while Egypt retained its independence; antiquities of the Perso-Egyptian period, while the country was subject to the Persians; antiquities of the Graeco-Egyptian period, or the period of the Ptolemies; and antiquities of the Romano-Egyptian period, while Egypt was a Roman province.

From Christopher Tuplin & ‎John Ma, Aršāma and his World: The Bodleian Letters in Context, volume 3 (2020):

... from his Perso-Egyptian glyptic choice. But the chances that the marriage of man and seal is correct must be accounted slim.
...
Documentary texts across the different strands of evidence do not often describe events of that sort [descriptions of exerting lethal force to maintain order or enhance state power]: one may mention the possibility implicit in P.Loeb 1 (protecting resources from brigands) or A6.7 (a hayla defending a fort from insurgents) and the actuality represented rather per4versely bu a Perso-Egyptian attack on the Judaean temple in 410 (A4.7//A4.8); by contrast the battle in Smith and Martin 2009: no. 5 is quite obscure.

And from M.A. Dandamaev, A Political History of the Achaemenid Empire (2023):

As to the above mentioned reconstruction of the passage of the Babylonian Chronicle, M. Boyce hs correctly stated that "the passage has been restored and interpreted in light of Perso-Egyptian propaganda against Cambyses ... rather than providing independent corroboration for it" (Boyce 1982:73, n. 15a).

The term "Perso-Egyptian" appears as a modifier in such phrases as "Perso-Egyptian advertisement," "Perso-Egyptian affairs," "Perso-Egyptian artistic style," "Perso-Egyptian common cause," "Perso-Egyptian conflict," "Perso-Egyptian decoration," "Perso-Egyptian emperors," "Perso-Egyptian fishing village," "Perso-Egyptian force," "Perso-Egyptian goddess," "Perso-Egyptian head," "Perso-Egyptian head-dress," "Perso-Egyptian interaction," "Perso-Egyptian marriage," "Perso-Egyptian officer," "Perso-Egyptian origin," "Perso-Egyptian peace treaty," "Perso-Egyptian relations," "Perso-Egyptian seal," "Perso-Egyptian silk," "Perso-Egyptian wars and revolts," "Perso-Egyptian work," and "Perso-Egyptian years." Most but not all of these instances refer to distant historical periods.
A Google Books search for "Irano-Egyptian" turns up nearly fifty confirmable unique matches, typically more modern in focus than the "Perso-Egyptian" instances cited above. Their range of publication dates are likewise relatively recent—from 1970 to 2024. Examples where "Irano-Egyptian appears as a modifier include "Irano-Egyptian alliance," "Irano-Egyptian amalgams," "Irano-Egyptian axis," "Irano-Egyptian chemical fertilizer project," "Irano-Egyptian communiqué," "Irano-Egyptian cooperation," "Irano-Egyptian diplomatic relations," Irano-Egyptian element," "Irano-Egyptian economic relations," "Irano-Egyptian friendship," "Irano-Egyptian hostility," "Irano-Egyptian investment bank," "Irano-Egyptian joint venture," com- muniqué  lrader," "Irano-Egyptian links," "Irano-Egyptian maritime company," "Irano-Egyptian movement," "Irano-Egyptian relations," "Irano-Egyptian rivalry," "Irano-Egyptian shipping company," "Irano-Egyptian ties," and "Irano-Egyptian yogas." As the nouns that appear in these examples suggest, the settings for these instances tend to be the modern (rather than ancient) world.

Conclusion
On the basis of the various Google Books matches I looked at, I would be inclined to use "Perso-Egyptian" if talking about ages of antiquity, but "Irano-Egyptian" if talking about the current era or the recent past.
